# SignalR Shapes app gives lag, is there a way to solve this?

Tags: azure, signalr

I hacked together a working version of the Shapes-demo:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034
(Shapes-demo starts around 5 mins)

Once uploaded to Azure, it became clear that there was some significant lag, the shape did move but it was far from real-time.

Is there an easy way to solve this?
I didn't find a suitable option when I looked it up, although I might have used the wrong search query..

Code:

```
$(function () {
var proxy = $.connection.moveShapeHub;
var $shape = $("#shape");

proxy.client.shapeMoved = function (x, y) {
    $shape.css({ left: x, top: y });
};

$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        $shape.draggable({
            drag: function () {
                proxy.server.moveShape(this.offsetLeft, this.offsetTop || 0);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks,
S.

Comment: Are you using a backplane or did you set up 2 local instances like they do in the demo or what is the overall architecture here?

Comment: @MarkC. I uploaded to Azure and tested both on 2 different computers (and networks) and 2 different browser-windows.  Lag is very noticeable. When running entirely locally it goes more than smooth enough.  Thanks for the reply!